# Remember Redemption

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to get a tattoo of the phrase "remember redemption 25 August 2105"  in Latin. This will commemorate the anniversary of my sobriety, along with the command to never forget God's grace and mercy in recovering from my addiction. How would this be translated into Latin?

Comment: Relevant question: are you giving an instruction to yourself to remember your redemption? Or to the world at large?

Comment: This would be for me alone

Comment: Ah, okay. I'd suggest editing that into the question then just to clarify!

Answer (score 4):

The standard word for "remember" (as in a command or request for a single person to remember) is *mementō*, as in *mementō morī*.

"Redemption", in the Christian sense, is *redemptiō*, literally "buying back". This is the word used in one of the psalms (48 in the Vulgate, 49 in most English versions):

> None of them can by any means **redeem** his brother, nor give to God a ransom for him: For the **redemption** of their soul is precious, and it ceaseth for ever.

*Mementō* can be followed by either a noun in the genitive case, which would be *redemptiōnis* "redemption", or by a phrase, *quia redemptus es* "that you were redeemed". (*Redemptus* would be used by a man, *redempta* by a woman.) Compare the phrase Rafael quoted: ***mementō quia pulvis es*** et in pulvus revertēris "**remember that you are dust** and to dust you shall return".

In summary, my suggestions are:

- *Mementō redemptiōnis [tuae]* = remember [your own] redemption
- *Mementō quia redemptus es* = remember that you (male) were redeemed
- *Mementō quia redempta es* = remember that you (female) were redeemed

The lines over some of the vowels can be included or left out, at your discretion. They represent a sound difference that vanished in later Latin; the Latin Vulgate Bible, for example, doesn't use them.

Comment: Regarding the date, if you want to keep it Ecclesiastical, I'd go for XXV augusti MMXV

Comment: Are you going for a late/liturgical Latin construction with ut redemptus/a sis? Because I don't think it's Classical Latin, where that would work only as an indirect question ('remember how you were redeemed'). Otherwise, just use an accusative+inf.: memento te redemptum/am esse.

Comment: @cnread also _quia_ redemptus sis/es (cf. _memento quia pulvus es et in pulverem reverteris_)

Comment: @Rafael Quia is a much better suggestion! Switched to use that

Comment: Don't forget the date!

Comment: [Pulv**i**s, -eris, m.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpulvis), my bad

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the alliteration of the English version you could say:

rememoramini redemptionem.

The first word is not used in classical Latin, but is known from Christian Latin. The second has a specifically Christian sense, as explained by Draconis.

Comment: Did you mean memoramini?

Comment: Why -āmini instead of -entō?

Comment: @Draconis. I have modelled this on  “remoramini pristinos dies,” Vulg. Heb. 10, 32.

Comment: Then I'd say it is ["re**me**moramini"](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Hbr.html#x10_32), unless [it is a version-thing](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vulsearch) (which could be perfectly possible). Both the Clementine Vulgate and the Nova Vulgata use rememoramini, which is more familiar to me. Remoramini sounds like a dat. or abl. of [remoramen](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dremoramen)

Comment: @Rafael. "Remoramini" seems to be a typo (horrors) in L & S. http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Drememoror I have corrected it in my answer.

Comment: Phew! I was scared. In fact if you go to the text you get [rememoramini](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0060%3Abook%3DHebrews%3Achapter%3D10%3Averse%3D32)

Comment: Remember that this is still plural. The singular version would be [_(re)memorare_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorare). I can think of an instance of "consolamini popule meus", but I'd say the key is that _populus_ implies many people.

Comment: @fdb But Hebrews 10:32 is addressing multiple people, isn't it? *Rememoramini* to me seems exclusively plural.

Comment: @Draconis. I was assuming that "remember redemption" is also addressed to the world at large. Of course the singular is (re)memorare.

Comment: @fdb Fair; commented on the main question to ask for clarification. I figured it was an instruction to a single person, like *mementō morī*.

Comment: It is for me alone, I am a woman, and I am extremely grateful for all of your carful consideration. Thank you.